# context.material.node_tree - context has no attribute to material?

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on, shaders, development

I am trying to write an addon, I am making a node group that will be created with a single button however I have run into issues with these final lines:

```
    custom_node_name = "dust"
    my_group = create_dust_group(self, context, custom_node_name)
    dust_node = context.material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')
    dust_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
    dust_node.use_custom_color = True
    dust_node.color = (0.5, 0.3, 0.9)
```

the problem I'm having is with the line

`dust_node = context.material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeGroup')`

I don't know how to get it to work for creating a material

any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Different contexts also can have different context members.**

> [**Context Access (`bpy.context`)**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#module-bpy.context)
>
> The context members available depend on the area of Blender which is
>   currently being accessed.

The properties panel is a classic example.  Looking at property panel code may come across `context.material` or `context.modifier` but will find them unavailable in say the python console.

```
>>> C.material
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'material'
```

Use another way to get material, from the active object

```
>>> C.object.active_material
bpy.data.materials['Material']
```

Re creating a material

[Add Nodes to Material with Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python)

[Python: Add existing NodeGroup to Material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150874/python-add-existing-nodegroup-to-material)

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful!