# How to invoke custom node operator

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, add-on

I am trying to invoke a custom operator from a blender addon, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/rgsouthall/vi-suite06/blob/1fea73a118f9a9060a9f22aaced54e8591fa6863/vi_operators.py#L593). However, when I call it from the command line I am getting the following error message:

```
>>> bpy.ops.node.liexport('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ttsesm/blender/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/vi-suite06/vi_operators.py", line 607, in invoke
    node = context.node
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'node'

location: /ttsesm/blender/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:199


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/ttsesm/blender/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 199, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ttsesm/blender/blender-2.83.2-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/vi-suite06/vi_operators.py", line 607, in invoke
    node = context.node
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'node'
```

from my understanding the explanation is related to what @batFINGER is describing [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/178221/106722). But then my question would be how to invoke the operator from the script.

The operator is related with the `Export` button that you can see in the node below:

[image]

and which node I created with the following commands:

```
ng = bpy.data.node_groups.new('NodeTree', 'ViN')
context_node = ng.nodes.new(type="No_Li_Con")
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found was to to override the `context.node` call. The way I did it was by creating a dictionary with 'node' as the key and the node as the item, e.g.

`override = {'node': bpy.data.node_groups[node_group_name].nodes['node_name']}`

The operator can then be run with `bpy.ops.node.ligexport(override, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'])`.

Comment: That'll do it. The node editor has an `active_node` and `node` (IIRC) context member.  Use  `layout.context_pointer_set("node", node)` to set it  in the layout if not using from node editor.

Comment: How is the `layout.context_pointer_set()` is defined? Because I am getting `NameError: name 'layout' is not defined`.

Comment: In draw code `layout = self.layout`  If it is used before an operator `layout.operator(...)` the operator will have that context member.  eg may be in the 3d view or properties UI.

Comment: Apologies, I do not understand what do you mean and how to use it :-(