# How to overide custom node operator variables in the execution

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, add-on

Related to the question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/198752/106722) I wanted now to use the [export custom node](https://github.com/rgsouthall/vi-suite06/blob/1fea73a118f9a9060a9f22aaced54e8591fa6863/vi_operators.py#L2184) from the same addon. Considering that the `invoke()` function calls the file browser for setting the path the filename I would like to call the `execution()` function directly but by overriding the `self.filepath` variable. I've tried to follow the same trick as in the linked question, meaning:

```
override = {'node': bpy.data.node_groups['<node_group_name>'].nodes['VI CSV Export'], 'self.filepath':'<path_to_save_file>.csv'}
bpy.ops.node.csvexport(override, 'EXEC_DEFAULT')
```

But this complaints with the following error:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/vi-suite06/vi_operators.py", line 2200, in execute
    node = self.node
  File "/ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 713, in __getattribute__
    return super().__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: 'NODE_OT_CSV' object has no attribute 'node'

location: /ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:199


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 199, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/vi-suite06/vi_operators.py", line 2200, in execute
    node = self.node
  File "/ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 713, in __getattribute__
    return super().__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: 'NODE_OT_CSV' object has no attribute 'node'

location: /ttsesm/blender-2.83.6-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:199
```

My questions are why the `node = self.node` cannot be overridden and whether the way that I am overriding the `self.filepath` variable is the correct one.

Comment: It's not a trick, you override context. _ie_ you are overriding  the operator what value `context.node` has. Not operator properties. Most likely want to use `bpy.ops.foo.bar(override, filepath="...")`

Comment: Why the `node = self.node` was not overridden by the `{'node': bpy.data.node_groups['<node_group_name>'].nodes['VI CSV Export']}` though? Like in the other case. I guess because it is not a `context` anymore, but then how I override it in this use case if possible.

Comment: if `self.node = context.node` is set in the invoke method of the operator also put in 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' as second argument like the other time.  The operator is designed to be invoked by pressing its button in the UI of the node.  (in this case you cannot bypass the invoke method by the looks)

Comment: but 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' will activate the `context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)` which I do not want, since I want to bypass this part.

Comment: As I suspected it is set in the invoke method See https://github.com/rgsouthall/vi-suite06/blob/1fea73a118f9a9060a9f22aaced54e8591fa6863/vi_operators.py#L2224   Does it still throw the filebrowser if the filepath is set?  Or edit addon to use `context.node` instead.  Not sure of the point of setting it as an operator property.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that the `self.node` is defined in the invoke(). If I give `bpy.ops.node.csvexport(override, filepath="test.csv")` it still hangs in the `node = self.node` line.

Answer (score 0):

**`self.node` is set in `invoke`.**

THe operator is designed to be invoked by pressing its button displayed on its node.

The operator defines

```
self.node = context.node
```

in its invoke method, and uses `self.node` in its `execute` method, and will hence not work unless invoked.

```
bpy.ops.foo.bar(override, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath=somefilepath)
```

IMO the simple fix is to edit the operator to use `context.node` as the node in place of `self.node` by placing

```
self.node = context.node
```

in the execute method also.

Alternatively return `self.execute(context)` from the invoke method if the value passed to `self.filepath` is a valid filepath and use

```
bpy.ops.foo.bar(override, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath=somefilepath)
```

to ensure it is invoked and node is set.

**A note on overriding.**

What you are passing in the override dictionary are context members, eg

```
override = {"foo" : "bar"}
```

then if passed as an override to  the operator

```
context.foo == "bar"
```

is true within the operator.

The `filepath` is a property of the operator, not the context and is hence not going to do diddly squat if passed as part of the override.  The operator (`self`) and context are not the same.  Pass it to the operator as a keyword variable.

**Fork it.**

Finally, fork and make the changes, or suggest / request  changes to the maintainer of the addon, so that it can be executed directly, or to find out if there are reasons why it cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @batFINGER. I try to ask the author to change the `node = self.node` to self.`node = context.node` if there is not any problem. Alternatively I can create and call my own method based on his `execute()` one for saving the file.